# How to split string into only two parts with a given character in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, split

Our application is mining names from people using Twitter to login.

Twitter is providing full names in a single string.

Examples

```
1. "Froederick Frankenstien"
2. "Ludwig Van Beethoven"
3. "Anne Frank"
```

I'd like to split the string into only **two** vars (`first` and `last`) based on the first `" "` (space) found.

```
Example    First Name    Last Name 
1          Froederick    Frankenstein
2          Ludwig        Van Beethoven
3          Anne          Frank
```

I'm familiar with `String#split` but I'm not sure how to only split once. The most Ruby-Way™ (elegant) answer will be accepted.

Comment: Ie 

```
"Ludwig Van Beethoven".split(' ', 2)
["Ludwig Van", "Beethoven"]
```

Not seeing an rsplit

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm looking for a native solution for the behavior i've stated before implementing myself. Currently I get the standard  ["Ludwig", "Van Beethoven"].

Answer (score 175, accepted):

String#split takes a second argument, the limit.

```
str.split(' ', 2)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I guess i'm **not** familiar (enough) with `String#split`. Thank you :)

Comment: Very nice, I didn't know split takes a second argument

Comment: Ie 

```
"Ludwig Van Beethoven".split(' ', 2)
["Ludwig Van", "Beethoven"]
```

Not seeing an rsplit

Comment: @Justin I got it working fine: `"a b c".split(" ", 2) # => ["a", "b c"]`

Answer (score 13):

```
"Ludwig Van Beethoven".split(' ', 2)
```

The second parameter limits the number you want to split it into.

You can also do:

```
"Ludwig Van Beethoven".partition(" ")
```

Comment: `split` and `partition` has different results: `"a b c".split(" ", 2) # => ["a", "b c"]; "a b c".partition(" ") # => ["a", " ", "b c"]`

Answer (score 8):

The second argument of `.split()` specifies how many splits to do:

```
'one two three four five'.split(' ', 2)
```

And the output:

```
>> ruby -e "print 'one two three four five'.split(' ', 2)"
>> ["one", "two three four five"]
```

Answer (score 6):

Alternative:

```
    first= s.match(" ").pre_match
    rest = s.match(" ").post_match
```

Comment: this will give an error if the match is not found (nil)